# Android - cant check if editText is empty

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to make sure my `editText` is not empty and i tried using `var.matches("")` and `var.isEmpty()` but it didn't work.
I found a tutorial on YouTube that uses Listener but my sdk says error.

```
public  void AddData() {
   convert();

        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
            if(validate){
                                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editCourseID.getText().toString(), editCourses.getText().toString(),
                                        editRoom.getText().toString(),
                                        editDay.getText().toString()
                                        , editTime.getText().toString()
                                        , editLecturer.getText().toString()
                                );
                                if (isInserted == true)
                                    Toast.makeText(AddSchedulel.this, "Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                else
                                    Toast.makeText(AddSchedule.this, "Data not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                            }

                }
        );

    MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
}



  public void convert(){
        courseID = editCourseID.getText().toString().trim();
        courses = editCourse.getText().toString().trim();
        room = editRoom.getText().toString().trim();
        day   = editDay.getText().toString().trim();
        time = editJam.getTime().toString().trim();
        lecturer = editLecturer.getText().toString().trim();

    }

public boolean validate(){
    boolean valid = true;
    if(courseID.matches("")){
         valid = false;
    }
    if(courses.matches("")){
        valid = false;
    }
    if(room.matches("")){
        valid = false;
    }
    if(day.matches("")){
        valid = false;
    }
    if(time.matches("")){
        valid = false;
    }
    if (lecturer.matches("")){
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

How can I do this? 
can someone help me to find what is wrong with my code

Comment: what error did you get? please share log cat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you setting the listener in the `AddData` method?
It is not very clear what you want to do but my impression is that you should call `convert()` in the onClick listener otherwise the variables will be set before the click.
Another thing is that you should not use match

```
private boolean validate(){
    return isNotEmpty(courseID) && isNotEmpty(courses);
}

private boolean isNotEmpty(String string) {
    return !string.equals("");
}
```

Comment: BTW `AddData` is not a good name for a method. You should use a lower letter for the first char. I don't know what you want to do with `MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();` but it looks horrible

Comment: Moved my `convert()`  in the onClick listener and changed the match to equals. It worked. thanks man you saved my life

Comment: Done. Sorry i'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Call if(validate()) instead of if(validate)

Comment: Sill didn't work.
I used if(validate()) and reinstalled my apps

Comment: use isEmpty() method, exapmple day.isEmpty(), can be work for you